# Can't compile Aseprite using CMake in VS2015

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I'm trying to make a Visual Studio solution with CMake to compile the latest version of Aseprite.

I already have Visual Studio 2015 and the DirectX SDK, and I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

I also found a post that had a similar but different issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found). Following this, I tried the command `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"`. The output of  this command is as follows:

```
C:\Users\LorddMichael\Downloads\aseprite-master\aseprite-master\build>cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23026.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23026.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDINT_H
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDINT_H - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SCHED_YIELD
-- Performing Test HAVE_SCHED_YIELD - Failed
-- Performing Test ASEPRITE_LITTLE_ENDIAN
-- Performing Test ASEPRITE_LITTLE_ENDIAN - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:100 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/src/flic

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

  CMake does not support this case but it used to work accidentally and is
  being allowed for compatibility.

  Policy CMP0014 is not set: Input directories must have CMakeLists.txt.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0014" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found DXGUID: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Lib/winv6.3/um/x86/dxguid.lib
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for include file gl/gl.h
-- Looking for include file gl/gl.h - not found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for include file memory.h
-- Looking for include file memory.h - found
-- Looking for include file rle.h
-- Looking for include file rle.h - not found
-- Looking for include file stdarg.h
-- Looking for include file stdarg.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - not found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for include file varargs.h
-- Looking for include file varargs.h - found
-- Looking for include file X11/Xlib.h
-- Looking for include file X11/Xlib.h - not found
-- Looking for include file X11/Xutil.h
-- Looking for include file X11/Xutil.h - not found
-- Looking for vprintf
-- Looking for vprintf - not found
-- Looking for _doprnt
-- Looking for _doprnt - not found
-- Looking for strdup
-- Looking for strdup - found
CMake Error at third_party/CMakeLists.txt:43 (message):
  gtest/gtest.h is missing.  Initialize submodules: git submodule update
  --init --recursive


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

C:\Users\LorddMichael\Downloads\aseprite-master\aseprite-master\build>cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:100 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/src/flic

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

  CMake does not support this case but it used to work accidentally and is
  being allowed for compatibility.

  Policy CMP0014 is not set: Input directories must have CMakeLists.txt.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0014" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at third_party/CMakeLists.txt:43 (message):
  gtest/gtest.h is missing.  Initialize submodules: git submodule update
  --init --recursive


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: ***C:/Users/LorddMichael/Downloads/aseprite-master/aseprite-master/src/flic*** I expect this means you have the wrong download or wrong folder since CMake requires a CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Looking further into the library: My guess is when you did a git clone you missed the `--recursive` parameter so did not clone the externals. flic is an external located on as a different repository. Without the source of this external CMake will fail.

Comment: @drescherjm It worked thanks :)

Comment: @LorddLazaro - I faced the same problem and then fixed it with the --recursive solution but I still did not get a bin folder with the executable. Can you share what you did to solve this ?