# cmake was unable to find a build program corresponding to Unix Makefiles

Tags: opencv, cmd, cmake, cygwin, gnu-make

I am trying to install openCV contrib modules as stated in a website as follows:

```
cd opencv\platfroms\
mkdir build_android_arm
cd build_android_arm
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -  
DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\android\android.toolchain.cmake ..\..
make
```

the problem i am facing is, when i try to run the commands mentioned above i got a message in the cmd as shown in the figure below

I have MinGW, CMake and GnuWin installed but i do NOT have visual Studio and i am working on a Windows operating system, but i do not know why the error message in the cmd mentions *Unix Makefiles*

please i need your help to solve my problem

**error message**

[image]

**update**:

[image]

**update2-**:
i delted the contents inside "android_arm" and i ran the command, and i got the message in the belwo picture

[image]

**update3*:
I also added the ANDROID_NDK to the system variables as shown in the image

[image]

but i still get the errors shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because on Windows (if not running the new Ubuntu bash) you can't give CMake "Unix Makefiles" as [a generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

Use `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` instead.

See the [`android.toolchain.cmake`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake#L36) file itself for more details:

> ```
> #  Usage Linux:
> #   $ export ANDROID_NDK=/absolute/path/to/the/android-ndk
> #   $ mkdir build && cd build
> #   $ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/the/android.toolchain.cmake ..
> #   $ make -j8
> #
> #  Usage Windows:
> #     You need native port of make to build your project.
> #     Android NDK r7 (and newer) already has make.exe on board.
> #     For older NDK you have to install it separately.
> #     For example, this one: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
> #
> #   $ SET ANDROID_NDK=C:\absolute\path\to\the\android-ndk
> #   $ mkdir build && cd build
> #   $ cmake.exe -G"MinGW Makefiles"
> #       -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path\to\the\android.toolchain.cmake
> #       -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="%ANDROID_NDK%\prebuilt\windows\bin\make.exe" ..
> #   $ cmake.exe --build .
> ```

Comment: please see the update section above..after i used the answer you provided i got an error message in the cmd as shown in the update section

Comment: @user2121 You have to delete the `build_android_arm` directory before trying again. CMake does not allow to switch generators after it has once started to generate an build environment.

Comment: @user2121 MinGW GCC package doesn't include make. The Readme as quoted in my answer suggests to use the make program shipped with Android NDK.

Comment: i ran the comands that are stated in your answer but i am still getting an error and i do not know how to solve it..please have a look at update3 section above

Comment: @user2121 Check your installations (CMake, MinGW, NDK, etc.) with small hello world examples (see also e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)). The problem for me is, that the possible causes for your new problems could be numerous (and I think have - like NDK/MinGW - already be discussed here on SO elsewhere). And please see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762) why I'm a little reluctant to continue answering an ever changing question.