# No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found even after trying all generators

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake-gui

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Basic. I tried all the 3 generators(Visual Studio 14 2015, Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64, and Visual Studio 14 2015 ARM ). still I am getting the this error.

> No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
>
> No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

Is there any thing else that I can do to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: Have you looked through this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found

Comment: I did. But I could not find the `vcvarsall.bat` file that it was talking about.

Comment: It should be at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`