# Cmake Error During Installation of dlib on Windows?

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, cmake, dlib

I am trying to install dlib-19.2 in Window 7.But during the building process of dlib I get these errors.

```html
Configuring cmake ...
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
    cl
  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
    cl
  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/dlib-19.2/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/dlib-19.2/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
error: cmake configuration failed!
```

Can anyone explain me the reason of the error and how to avoid it.Cmake GUI seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE\_C\_COMPILER could be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found). The error message you have shown also does contain a list of things you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, installing Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools solved it for me:
http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: This link is now broken