# CMake Compiler Identification Error

Tags: gcc, cmake

I'm having the following problem when trying to build a project using CMake:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
```

I'm executing the following command: `cmake .` inside the CMake project folder.

The error also states that I shoulkd try to set the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER enviroment variables to the compiler paths. And so did I. 
I've set the variables to the following paths, respectively: `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` and `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`.

The error kept happening. 
My CMakeLists looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (hello)
add_executable(hello helloworld.cpp)
```

I have no CMake knowledge at all so consider that it is possible that I've forgotten some basic stuff.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE\_C\_COMPILER could be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

I was not choosing the correct generator, and the following fixed it:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

After selecting MinGW generator, everything worked just fine.