# Trying to build qgis - set path to Bison and flex?

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, qgis

I'm trying to follow the step by step instructions for building QGIS in a Windows environment hence I've got some difficulties to understand where I shall set the paths for Bison and flex in CMAKE and where do I find the option BINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL?
I removed the @echo off in the bash script and before I run `cmake-gui` I gets following output in the cmd.

```
C:\Users\Matrix\Desktop>set VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\
C:\Users\Matrix\Desktop>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26430.6
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64' Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Matrix\Desktop>cmake-gui
```

I've also tried to run a small hello world script in c++ within visual studio which worked as expected.

I've uploaded a print screen from my CMAKE Error message
[image: Error message]
The C compiler identification is unknown

The CXX compiler identification is unknown

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (PROJECT):

No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (PROJECT):

No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found

Comment: I believe that visual studio is found and set before I run `cmake-gui`