# How to build GLFW without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

I've downloaded the GLFW [source package](http://www.glfw.org/download.html), run CMake, and all I get is a Visual Studio solution folder. I'm running MinGW through a POSIX subsystem on a Windows environment, so I don't think the VC++ binaries are going to work for me. Is there any way I can get a proper Makefile?

Comment: In Windows, I think cmake will generate visual studio solution by default. To generate another target, you need to specify the target via `-D"MinGW Makefiles"`. More info can be found by running `cmake --help`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found/

Comment: @CroCo in my case, it was `-G"MSYS Makefiles". everything is compiled and working now. sweet, thanks.