# CMake Error : execution of make failed on Windows

Tags: cmake, mingw, nanomsg

I am getting errors when trying to build [nanomsg project](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg) in Windows 7:

```
cmake ..
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_5d837\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/cmake-3.9.4-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not
able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/User/Documents/Internal/nanomsg-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_5d837\fast"



Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
"cmTC_5d837\fast"





CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:29 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User/Documents/Internal/nanomsg-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/User/Documents/Internal/nanomsg-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I use `gcc` compiler and `make` from `Mingw` toolchain and I can run succesfully `gcc.exe` and `mingw32-make.exe` on a simple example.

In the file `CMakeCache.txt` the cache variables are set as follows:

```
//C compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe

//Program used to build from makefiles.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:STRING=nmake
```

I think that the problem comes from `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` variable it should take `C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe`, however i dont understand from where it gets the value `nmake`.

Even i replaced it manually I get the same problem.

My questions :

- How CMake fills the Cache variables ?
- Why `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` takes the value `nmake` ?
- Why changing manually this variable didn t solve the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE\_C\_COMPILER could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found). You need to specify a generator in CMake command line like `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` and - depending on how many compilers you have installed - also the full paths to the compilers.

Comment: @Florian, Thank you for the feedback, OK that resolves the problem :). Just what happened when I changed the generator does CMake has internal scripts that searches for the c compiler and make program and then updates the cache variables because now I can see that the variables have good values in CMakeCache.txt

Comment: @Mouin - `nmake` is Microsoft's make tool. You can get a copy of it from the [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). You no longer need to download Visual Studio or deal with the expiring trials. The Build Tools are a subset of the Visual Studio tools, and it include a compiler, linker, nmake, and a few other essential tools for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

CMake fills the cache file with the values it detects based what is in `CMakeLists.txt` and whatever files it includes in combination with any `-D` paramters supplied to `cmake`.

On Windows CMake will default to Microsoft's `nmake` tool. The way to override this is by passing parameter `-G"MinGW Makefiles"` to `cmake`, or in case you use MSYS shell `-G"MSYS Makefiles"`.

But there is a faster build tool than `make` called Ninja (get it from https://ninja-build.org/) which you can use by passing `-GNinja` to `cmake`.

Note: I see you're using the old MinGW that comes with Code::Blocks. There is a more up to date successor to MinGW called MinGW-w64, which supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit. A recent standalone build can be downloaded from https://winlibs.com/ and it also includes `ninja.exe`.

P.S.: If you run into more issues building the nanomsg sources after following these tips, consider passing `-DNN_TESTS:BOOL=OFF` to `cmake`