# build C++ source code as a library with "MinGW Makefile" generator using CMake on Windows7

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, mingw

I am trying to build C++ source code as a library with "MinGW Makefile" generator using CMake on Windows7.

I have followed this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found/32830625#32830625) and I am getting  till "mingw32-make" to compile.

I have installed MinGW and rooted in PATH.

I have used CMake-gui and I have successfully done configuration with "MinGW Makefile" generator.

The Generation process also done successfully without any warnings.

Then I have open command window with release directory path and executed "mingw32-make".

Generally I know after execution, the system will generated library files. 
But, I seeing errors after invocation of "mingw32-make". [error statement in command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxcmM.png)

Comment: You have installed MinGW and its compilers? In a location that CMake can find them (i.e. in the `PATH`)?

Comment: Reworded for better readability. But I agree to the other comment: you should rather give more details here. Maybe a list of steps, and a small note if that worked, or if there were warnigns/errors?!

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Yes I have installed MinGW and rooted in PATH. I have used CMake-gui and I have successfully done configuration with "MinGW Makefile" generator. The Generation process also done successfully without any warnings. Then I have open command window with release directory path and executed "mingw32-make". Generally I know after execution, the system will generated library files. But, I couldn't see any progress, warnings or errors.

Comment: Your last comment contains information, which should be **in the question** itself. Please, [edit] your question post and add this information into it. This is how Stack Overflow works: The question should be clear for others *without* reading the comments and following the links. You write "I couldn't see any progress, warnings or errors" after invocation of `mingw32-make`. But what actually do you see? Does the command waits something, or it outputs nothing and returns immediately?

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your feedback and I have updated my question itself.

Comment: Reinstalled packages with correct version & rooted with proper environment variable PATH.              Thanks @Tsyvarev