# MVSC 2022 - EXIV2 error - No CMAKE_C_COMPILER - Conan install failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, conan, exiv2

Using Windows 10 machine. I have cloned exiv2 from GitHub with MVSC 2022, which I configured with Visual C++ 2022.

I have also installed Conan on my machine, and Conan is in the path.

When CMake parses the CMakeLists.txt file, I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at D:\c-repos\exiv2-mvsc2\CMakeLists.txt:66 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.   exiv2   D:\c-repos\exiv2-mvsc2\CMakeLists.txt   66

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at build-base_windows/conan.cmake:651 (message):
  Conan install failed='1'      D:\c-repos\exiv2-mvsc2\build-base_windows/conan.cmake   651
```

Comment: `Is CMake able find and run with any/your default compiler? Run without giving a generator` https://stackoverflow.com/a/32830625/16764520

Comment: You need to provide more details: which repo are you cloning is this one https://github.com/jmue/exiv2? Who is calling Conan is the CMakeLists.txt in the repo? What is the full output?